# Trying to understand UIAnimation paths

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am trying to get my animation move in more than one generated path. I got my codes down but I still don't get what is wrong with it.

Here is where I place my image in the view

```
UIImageView *faceAni = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 100, 50.0, 50.0)];
        faceAni.animationImages = faces;
        faceAni.animationDuration = 10;
        faceAni.animationRepeatCount = 0;
        [faceAni startAnimating];
        [self addSubview:faceAni];
```

And here is where I try to get the animation to move in a triangular path coordinates.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];


        [UIView animateWithDuration:4 
                              delay:0 
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse  
                         animations:^{faceAni.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);} 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:4 
                                  delay:0 
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse  
                             animations:^{faceAni.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(faceAni.transform, -100, 0);} 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [UIView animateWithDuration:4 
                                      delay:0 
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse 
                                 animations:^{faceAni.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(faceAni.transform, 300, 0);} 
                                 completion:NULL];

            }];

        }];
```

I still don't get what is wrong with my codes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help if you describe the behaviour that you're seeing. As a guess, though, you probably don't want the `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` flags you're passing to each animation.

Comment: Because I want them to continue animating as a loop. So it is supposde to move in a triangular shape. But however as the image only moves from ( 200, 100) to (0, 200), so basically it's just moving up and down but not moving in any of the other two coordinates that I input.

Comment: Right; so, just have your final completion block (which is currently NULL) start the animations again, and remove the options flags.

Comment: wow thank you, it's moving in the coordinates now but however it doesn't repeat when it reach the last coordinates. Should I have the options back just in last UIView coorindates options?

Comment: No, that will just repeat the last animation. You should have a completion block on the last animation that calls the method to run the animation again. If you found my answer helpful, it's polite to accept it by clicking the checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little lost. In my completion block what method should I call?

Comment: Whichever method the code you posted was from. The method with `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]` in it.

Comment: I am so terribly sorry, to be honest I still don't quite understand. Do I still use UIView setAnimationRepeatCount to the method? or.